# Changed by mistake the grub default boot to memtest, now cant get back to the grub menu nor to boot from a live cd

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

Little background - I'm a complete noob, I wanted to make my grandparents a "present" and install linux on their old PC. Most of my knowledge come from the day or 2 that took me to research what and how to install for my grandparents. I've installed Lubuntu (can't remember the version, it was few months ago) and they liked it very much because they couldn't break it too much and I was happy as well because I didn't need to repair it every other week. Few days ago they had some problem with the camera and they called some friend that was using linux to try and help them, unfortunately I gave him the administrator password and he did something. Yesterday I came to help them because the PC won't boot.

Closer to the problem: the PC wont boot and stop at an error like "alert dev/disk/by-uuid/***somethingLong*** does not exist" I tried searching online but couldn't get something related. I've noticed that I get a grub menu at the start where I can chose some options and if I chose not the default "ubuntu" but the "advanced options for ubuntu"(cant remember the exact wording) there I can chose the newest version(I think its the version of lubuntu) or the newest version with safe start or the older version or the older version with safe start etc. I chose to boot the older version and the pc starts normally.

The problem itself: I've search how to change the default boot option in grub and found that I need to edit the grub file. I've edited the grub file but as I understand I've written the wrong values there so now the pc automatically boots into memtest(Memtest86 v4.20).

What I've tried:

- I couldn't find a way to get back to the grub menu when the pc starts, if I restart the pc it goes again automatically to the memtest.
  If I let the memtest run it will just run it in cycles - I don't think there is a point where it will end and go past it to load the os.
- I can't load live cd from a USB - I've tried changing the boot options in the bios to usb-ffd, usb-zip, usb-cdrom and non of them boot even when I tried to stick the usb to the back usb ports of the pc or the front usb ports. By can't boot I mean it boots just as usual and going straight to the memtest, even though the usb was flashing it's lights as if the pc was reading files from it.
- I couldn't load the live cd from a CD (I can't get my hands on a dvd so I found several live cds that fit into a cd) and I still cant boot. This time I get a line "Boot from CD: " it hangs for a few seconds then either it continue to boot to memtest or it writes something like: "could not boot from cd insert the install cd and press enter". I was able to boot from this cd on other pc so it might be that the cdrom is broken on the not bootable pc but I dont think so (I installed lubunto a few months ago, i'm not sure if it was from a usb or a dvd but I did install it somehow)

So now I'm basicly stuck with a pc that boots automatically to memtest and I cant do anything.

Any suggestions?

ps- sorry for the bad English, it's not my native language.

Comment: Aren't you able to boot to Live DVD?

Comment: I'm not able to boot from a live cd that I burned to a CD (I can't get my hands on a DVD today)

Comment: Don't you have anyway to boot to a Live environment?

Comment: I tried what I read online... live cd from usb or from a cd/dvd. Do you have other suggestion? I saw an option to boot from "legacy lan" in the boot menu but I didn't research it.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Comment: Try pressing shift repeatedly right after you turn your computer on. That should bring the GRUB menu.

Comment: How did you install Lubuntu if you can't boot to a live environment? Or is this a new problem?

Comment: Eduardo Cola, you are the man. I was able to show grub before the evil memtest and boot to the os where I fixed my mistake. Please leave an answer so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eduardo Cola suggested, I pressed shift repeatedly to enter the GRUB menu before the start of the memtest then in the GRUB menu I was able to select to boot to the desirable OS where I could undo my earlier mistake.