# PC Memtest not ending with escape

Tags: memtest

I was on help earlier today because of an error I was getting trying to update Ubuntu.  WHen I got off help, my tech initiated my updates.  It started a PCMem test when done, that is not stopping.  If I hit esc it restarts.  If I shut down my computer, when it reboots it starts the memtest again.  How can I end the test and reboot my computer?

Comment: You've provided few actual specifics, we don't know what Ubuntu product you're using, what release of that *unstated* product, and importantly what memory test you're talking about - is it a machine firmware test? from your Ubuntu system? etc (*we have few details of that nor how you started the test*). Currently your question is unclear & would benefit from someone how can see the issue.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.  The test that keeps running is PCMem Test-64 v1.5

Comment: Please be specific; what Ubuntu 22.04 ?  Server? Desktop? etc..  The program you mention is from where?   That doesn't match what I'd expect to see on a Ubuntu 22.04 system (eg. https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.2/ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest if using desktop, https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/memtest86+ being the app included - though you've not said which 22.04 system!)

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changed by mistake the grub default boot to memtest, now cant get back to the grub menu nor to boot from a live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713336/changed-by-mistake-the-grub-default-boot-to-memtest-now-cant-get-back-to-the-gr)